# ¿Cómo ingresar valores en un array usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
var sum = [];
var value1 = [];
var value2 = [];

for(i=1;i<=1000;i++){
    var result = '';
    if(i % 3 == 0){
        result+=' multiplo de 3: '+i;
    }
    if(i % 5 == 0){
       result+=' multiplo de 5: '+i;
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Saludos, lo que deseo hacer es ingresar todos los múltiplos de 3 y de 5 en dos arrays distintos, para sumarlos ¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: te invito a que visites [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays) para que puedas obtener mas conocimiento de como tratar con arrays en javascript, siempre es bueno leer documentacion

Answer (score 2):

Debes usar [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Este método inserta elementos dentro de un array

```js
const miArray = [];
miArray.push("Hola mundo");
console.log(miArray) // ["Hola mundo"]
```

Este método **Reasigna** el array, por lo que no tendrás que reasignarlo con el valor de devolución del método

---

En tu código veo un error:

```
console.log(result)
```

No estará definido, ya que solo es válido durante el bucle y el bucle tampoco está haciendo gran cosa, ya que siempre se va a reiniciar `result`, recuerda que `var` define una variable global, a no ser que se defina en una función o bucle

Tu solución quedaría así

```js
var sum = [];
var value1 = []; // múltiplos de 3
var value2 = []; // múltiplos de 5
var result = '';

for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
    if(i % 3 == 0){
        result+=' multiplo de 3: '+i+" ";
        value1.push(i);
    }
    if(i % 5 == 0){
       result+=' multiplo de 5: '+i+" ";
       value2.push(i);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Además, no te recomiendo para nada hacer un bucle tan largo: `<=1000`, ya que eventualmente te traerá problemas

Comment: Solo una aclaración: Cuando declaras una variable con `var` dentro del ciclo, queda disponible en el contexto actual, no solo en el bloque. Esa limitación solo se logra mediante `let` o `const`.